# Django doesn't remember context

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm new to Django and i'm trying to set up an existing project on new server.

Django starts, but it behaves very strange. I have the following code:

```python
someVar = None

def first(request):
    global someVar
    someVar = 'modified'

def second(request):
    return HttpResponse(someVar) # prints 'None'
```

I mapped this methods to URLs. When I call 'first' method and then 'second', the expected output is 'modified', but actually it is 'None'

It seems like Apache starts the application on each request, like if it was some cgi script. Any ideas why this is happening?

I'm using Apache2.2 with mod_wsgi and Django 1.5.9. 
Django project is outside of Apache's document root. Here is Apache host configuration file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/mysite

<Directory /path/mysite/mysite>
     <Files wsgi.py>
         Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module-level variables are only shared between requests that use the same process. Apache is almost certainly spinning up multiple processes to serve your site. If your subsequent requests happen to go to the same process that served the initial one, you will see the change; otherwise you won't.

If you really need to share data between requests no matter which process serves them, you should use a more persistent place, such as the session or the database.